# What version of GNU GCC supports the TR1 extern templates?

Tags: c++, gcc, external, tr1

What is the earliest [GNU GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (g++) version to support the `TR1` [extern templates](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-06/msg00159.html)? For example, is it already supported in version 4.0?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the list of C++-0x features supported and the G++ version that supports them [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).  There is a simple Yes in the column so I assume they're in 4.3 or possibly earlier.

Comment: The linked page shows the compiler version now if the feature is supported.

Comment: But not in the case of "extern templates".  It's simply a Yes there.  However, IIRC it was people from GCC that proposed the idea, so it's possible that it has been in g++ for several versions.

Answer (score 4):

Per Richard's answer, this feature apparently came from gcc, where (according to [the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template%20Instantiation)) it has existed since at least gcc 3.2.3.